# Using PHPMyAdmin to administer Amazon RDS

Tags: phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I can't get PHPMyAdmin to connect to my Amazon RDS instance.  I've granted permissions for my IP address to the DB Security Group which has access to this database I'm trying to access.  Here's what I'm working with...

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

    /* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

    /* Advance to next server for rest of config */
    $i++;
}

    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';  //is this correct?
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'MASTER-USER';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MASTER-USER-PASSWORD';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|phpmyadmin)';
    /* Server parameters */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MY-DB.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connection_type'] = 'socket';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = PORT;
```

I'm not sure if my configuration is correct.

I'm getting this error:

> #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found most of the answers in this question lack explanation. To add RDS server in phpMyAdmin installed in EC2, you can first login to your EC2 via SSH. Then, issue the following command to edit the Config file of phpMyAdmin (use `vi`, `nano` or any other favorite text editing tool):

```
sudo vi /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php # Amazon Linux
sudo vi /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php # Ubuntu Linux
```

Find the following lines in `config.inc.php`:

```
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */
```

Append the following lines **above** the "End of servers configuration" line:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'YOUR_SERVER_NAME';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
```

which `YOUR_SERVER_NAME` is the name being displayed in phpMyAdmin login page's selection box. If you remove this line, the whole RDS hostname will be displayed in the selection box (which is too long, obviously). Remember to save the `config.inc.php`.

There are several other config settings, which you can find the details in the [official documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html).

---

**Note:** The other answer suggests auto login with preset username & password in Config file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
```

which is **extremely dangerous** if your phpMyAdmin is exposed to public. You don't want to show your database schema to everyone, do you? If you really want to use automatic login, make sure your phpMyAdmin is accessible via specific IPs only.

Comment: I had to add my EC2 instance's private IP address to the inbound rules of the security group which my RDS instance was using in order to allow mysql connections to it. Just leaving it here for anyone having connection issues.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. Yes, adding inbound rule is essential for a working connection.

Answer (score 22):

In Debian Lenny using the phpmyadmin from the repo add this to /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Comment: I found that specifying the port caused a log-in error. Also you can use 'auth_type' cookie and not specify user and password.

Answer (score 14):

You need to add the RDS instance as an additional server listed on PHPMyAdmin while granting the host PHPMyAdmin access to your RDS instance.

More details from this blog post on [How to remotely manage an Amazon RDS instance with PHPMyAdmin](http://blog.benkuhl.com/2010/12/how-to-remotely-manage-an-amazon-rds-instance-with-phpmyadmin/):

> The one thing I had trouble with was the DB Security Group setup.  When you go to add access for an CIDR/IP it provides a recommended value.  It took some messing around to determine that this default value isn’t actually what needed to be there.  If you’re not able to connect to your instance when it’s all said and done, be sure to double check this value.  The IP they provided did not match the IP address that was provided to us by our ISP.  Once you’ve created your DB Instance and setup the security group you’re good to go.
>
> I’m going to assume you’ve already got PHPMyAdmin up and running.  What you need to do is modify config.inc.php to recognize the new server.

Comment: Please do not just post links as answer. Post answer as text, and if needed, provide the link for further explanation. This way, if the link drops dead, the answer will still be there.

Comment: If your RDS is in a VPC
In regards to the security groups, AWS has a tutorial on connecting from EC2 to RDS within a VPC here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html
In particular you need to edit the VPC security group inbound rule to add the id of the security group that your EC2 instance is in (or if not using EC2 then the IP of the server you want to access the RDS)

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: Link is still dead, answer is useless.  This is why we don't use links.

Comment: Link is dead, here is the page from Wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20160322111825/http://blog.benkuhl.com/2010/12/how-to-remotely-manage-an-amazon-rds-instance-with-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 10):

Try to connect from the mysql command line (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) and see what's this utility returns you. I found it's easier to debug that way.

```
mysql -hMY-DB.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -uMASTER-USER -pPASSWORD
```

If that's doesn't work, it means your amazon RDS security aren't configured correctly. (which is the common problem).

Comment: Using incompatible security group will cause this, thank you.

Comment: This helped me rule out RDS, hostname, username and password.  Unfortunately no matter how I set up my config I still get #2002

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

--ADD LINES BELOW THE PMA CONFIG AREA AND FILL IN DETAILS--
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
```

Save and Exit. Refresh your phpmyadmin page and you'll see a dropdown with the server that you just added[image]

Source: https://github.com/andrewpuch/phpmyadmin_connect_to_rds, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz-4wTGD2_Q

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and nothing of the above solved it.

As it turned out the thing was in "Publicly Accessible" option of the RDS instance. When you create your instance this option is "no" by default and there is no place you can change it.

However, after creating the RDS instance you can make its snapshot, then delete the instance and then launch the snapshot. In launch options just set "Publicly Accessible" to "yes" and your phpMyAdmin will finally see you RDS MySql server.

Beware that DNS of the original RDS instance and the snaphot are different so you would have to change your 'host' in config.inc.php

Cheers :)

Comment: amazing, i already figured this out but i found no other answers related to this.Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

First try this :

**mysql -h xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xx-xx-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -p**  // Your RDS server.

If it waits and doesn't prompt for the password then you would need to check security group and add 3306 outbound to your Web Tier.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect from the cli using `mysql -h ENDPOINT -u USERNAME -p` but not from PHPMyAdmin or your own web scripts, don't forget to [tell selinux to let your web server talk to the network](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans#line-44) :)

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarily, possible things you need to check when somehow the phpMyAdmin seems not to connect to the config file at all.

1. RDS instance must be *Publicly Accessible*. You can go to the AWS console and modify the RDS instance again to switch it on.
2. RDS instance must open the firewall (*Inbound* rules).

- Type: `MySQL`
- Protocol: `TCP`
- Port: `3306` (default)
- Source: `0.0.0.0/0` --> For all access. Or Your server IP/32 (ex: `54.209.7.206/32`) --> For specific access.

3. `'auth_type'` in `config.inc.php` must be `'cookie'` (default)
4. config.inc.php must have the permissions of reading and executing. Command (Centos): `sudo chmod -R 555 /etc/phpMyAdmin`

Answer (score -1):

I use ubuntu shell to access Amazon RDS.
first of all go to ubuntu root

```
sudo -i
```

to do this use amazon RDS end user URL

```
mysql -h gelastik.cqtbtepzqfhu.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -p
```