# phpmyadmin for RDS

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I decided to put an AWS related Q here after having asked on aws dev forum and did not find a solution.

I have also followed the steps given on a repeat question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds)

Can someone please tell me where I am making the wrong move.

My EC2 instance is in us-west-1c (linux) and has phpmyadmin installed in it.
My RDS is also in us-west-1c
My security grp common to EC2 and RDS has http/ssh/mysql ports configured.

I am able to connect to my rds from my instance using mysql_connect() in php,
but if I give my rds endpoint as a host in phpmyadmin (config.inc.php) it does not respond.

This is how my config.inc.php looks like

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xx.amazonaws.com';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = true;
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxx';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxx';

Am I missing something here ?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow outside connections in the httpd conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Update it to:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

You only need to update the following in the phpmyadmin/config

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'somerandomtext';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxx-your-service-host.rds.amazonaws.com';
```

Hope this helps.