# How to get phpmyadmin access on Amazon RDS Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon web services and I have no knowledge of operate this service. I recently created a mysql database using Amazon RDS and now want to access phpmyadmin to import an existing database to Amazon RDS.

What's the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHPMyAdmin to administer Amazon RDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way of configuring phpadmin on you local machine or server to connect straight to your amazon database, but this would require you to have the connection string for your amazon database. look around the settings for your amazon database server and get the IP/URL, db_name, user_name and password. After getting all these files follow these steps

1. Goto your phpadmin folder i.e. (yours may require ftp to your server)  C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14
2. locate the configuration file config.inc.php
3. Copy it to create a backup
4. Open it in a text editor
5. find this block of code and copy it (the whole block)

   ```
   $i++;
   /* Authentication type */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
   //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   /* Server parameters */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
   /* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   ```
6. change the copy below to match your amazon site, host is the ip/url of the database server, user is for user-name and password...
7. close the config file and restart/relaunch the phpadmin
   [image: Drop Down]
8. on the drop down under Current Server you can find the amazon server you added
9. this same technique works to add different database servers to your phpadmin

Comment: I'm not sure how this works but I'm attemping to connect my phpmyadmin to my aws rds mysql db. I'm getting the standard error: Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.