# How to access my database in PHPMyAdmin from a different computer?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am working on my Java application in Eclipse that connects to the database and makes some queries with the data. This database has been created and managed in PHPMyAdmin. The database is stored locally and now I would like to make it accessible not only from my computer, but for anyone who will run my application on his computer. Can anyone tell me what is the procedure? How can I make the database "online"? Should I store the database on some remote server? If so, what is the procedure?

I know this question is not so much straight-forward, but I hope you will give me some idea how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you should store the database on an external server who are better at managing databases with more security/backups etc.

If you're looking for scalability as well you could get an [Amazon AWS Micro Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) in the cloud for free for a year which includes a large amount (20GB) of [RDS (their relational database service based on MySQL)](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) for free.

There is a great Stack Overflow question on [Using PHPMyAdmin to administer Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds) as well to get you started with something you are familiar with.

You can use [MySQLDump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to copy your current database from your local machine to RDS if you needed.

#### (A, completely non-extensive, list of) Mysql Hosting Providers

- [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com) - Good web user interface. Does more than just database hosting. Lots of [documentation](http://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/databases.html).
- [Amazons RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) - Cloud based. Reliable. Offers [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)
- [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/databases/) - Cloud based. Excellent customer service.

#### Or, host your own on something like these

- [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) - Has lots of documentation of getting [Mysql installed](http://library.linode.com/databases/mysql)
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) - SSDs for great speed. Again great documentation on getting [Mysql installed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/a-basic-mysql-tutorial)

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. So what you suggest is to should move my database to Amazon RDS and connect to my database in my Java application from there?

Comment: Yes - that way you have a fast, reliable, secure, centralised system that anyone with your Java application can access.

Rather than having to keep your computer on all the time, on a slower connection with no back ups :-)

Comment: Thanks, however are you sure that the service is for free, I was trying to register to Amazon WMS and they say they will give me free access for one month, however, after that they will start charging me for the service.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/free/ This will give you a 'Micro Instance' for free for 1 year. It will give you a micro linux server in the cloud and you can use the management console online to create your database. There is a Getting started with the free tier guide here; http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-freetier/TestDriveFreeTier.html

Comment: yeah, I have realized that. However, when creating an account, they require my CC deatils and stress that "Your credit card will not be charged until you begin using AWS, and many of your applications and uses of AWS may be able to operate within the AWS free usage tier. If your monthly usage goes beyond the free tier, your AWS service charges will be billed to the credit card you provide below. View detailed service pricing". I have no clue when my database could start being charged, here are the pricing details: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

Comment: Yup, you do have to monitor your usage to make sure you don't go over. However as stated here aws.amazon.com/free you get; 1) 750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ Micro DB Instances a month; 2)20 GB of database storage; 3) 10 million I/Os. If you go over these or use any of the services not detailed on that page you will be charged per hour. The price varies. I will update my answer to include non-cloud based services however you will not find many 'free' ones.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29607/discussion-between-kisamoto-and-michalb)