# Access from PHPMyAdmin to Amazon RDS on Mac

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I need to access Amazon RDS via PHP MyAdmin.
As I am a beginner I am really struggling. I have found a post with a similar problem:
[Using PHPMyAdmin to administer Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds)
pointing to:
http://blog.benkuhl.com/2010/12/how-to-remotely-manage-an-amazon-rds-instance-with-phpmyadmin/

The answer in there just messed up my complete config.inc.php file.
I had to re-install XAMPP including PHPMyAdmin to get access to the localhost again.

Can somebody tell me what is the best way to proceed?
Is it correct that I can access Amazon RDS from local PHPMyAdmin?

Thank you

Edit:
Have seen that the code in the file needs to start with

```
$i++;
```

Does somebody know how the code should look like in the end?

adding:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|phpmyadmin)';
    /* Server parameters */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxxxx.l2kj35ncj3.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
```

Did not work for me.

Edit 2:
Is it correct that I find the file under:
"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin"

my config.inc.php file looks different from the one in the tutorial.

```
<?php

/* $Id: config.sample.inc.php,v 2.1.2.2 2006/08/28 08:14:14 nijel Exp $ */
// vim: expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4:

/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for 
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use scripts/setup.php
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin 
 * wiki <http://wiki.cihar.com>.
 */

/* 
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in 
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/* 
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/* 
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/* User for advanced features */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pmauser';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';

/* 
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have your local IP address in the DB security group that your RDS instance belongs to.

Go to the RDS section of the AWS Management Console.

On the lefthand side of the page, click on "DB Instances".  Select the instance you are trying to access and make a note of which security group it belongs to.

Now, on the lefthand side of the page, click on "DB Security Groups".  Select that the security group you made a note of.  One the bottom of the page there should be a form field that says CIDR.  Below it you will see the best estimate for the CIDR of your local machine.  Copy and paste that into the CIDR box and click the Add button.

Now try accessing the database from your local machine.