# phpMyAdmin causing failed connections

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I am running phpMyAdmin on an amazon EC2 ubuntu lamp stack, configured to use a remote RDS server.

I have run the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` configuration script, accessed RDS using the `master username` and `master password` (not `rdsadmin` but that set on initialisation), and can log into the phpMyAdmin console.

However, every refresh of the phpMyAdmin interface creates a new failed connection. In the logs I see:

```
2014-01-14 23:42:20 12879 [Warning] Access denied for user 
'phpmyadmin'@'[IP address]' (using password: YES)
```

What is the best way to try and debug this?

**SOLVED**

For reference, when using EC2 with RDS and the phpmyadmin installation wizard above, the control user is set to use an unresolvable host, such as `ip-[EC2 IP ADDRESS].eu-west-1.compute.internal`. Simply changing the host to your actual EC2 IP address allows the connection to become valid and failed connections no longer occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you've configured a controluser in your config.inc.php file (naming the controluser 'phpmyadmin'), but that isn't actually a valid user on the server. If that's the case, you could resolve it by either removing that line from the configuration or creating the user using the script provided (normally in the "examples" folder, but who knows where it is in the Ubuntu file system).

Try `grep phpmyadmin config.inc.php` on the configuration file and see if anything interesting is found.

Though, come to think of it, normally Ubuntu handles that sort of thing for you, so it's possible you've got a larger misconfiguration going on here. I'd also try reconfiguring it (`dpkg-reconfigure --plow phpmyadmin`) and see if you can get any further.

Are there any error or warning messages displayed within phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, I get `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.`. There is no phpmyadmin username in `config.inc.php`, but there is a definition in `config-db.php`

Comment: There's a difference between $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']. There's no field called 'username'. Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing. This error relates to the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] (and corresponding $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']) fields. Did you try the dpkg-reconfigure command with any success?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the EC2 ip address to the RDS security group ?

Check this a similar link [Using PHPMyAdmin to administer Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds)

Thanks