# Wordpress on AWS with phpmyadmin for easy DB administration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I've been working on this for many hours.

I want to host Wordpress sites within AWS but also have phpmyadmin access to the databases for easy swapping of client sites/files/theming/updating etc. . .

I've successfully set up wordpress blogs on micro instances running lamp stacks, and have used amazon's RDS as the database, can connect to php my admin but don't know how to configure it to display the database from the related installation?

Severely new at this thank you

Comment: Set the database hostname? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details... this might be duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds but without any information, can't even tell if that's the case