# Nginx Centos 7 cannot view RDS through PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, centos7, amazon-rds

I am having an AWS instance installed with **Centos 7** and **Nginx** and **PHP 7.1**.

**SELinux** is disabled on the server.

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to access the RDS using PhpMyAdmin. I have added my RDS configurations in the PhpMyadmin config file but not able to view the host in PMA.

**Note:**  I am able to connect to the RDS using the instance terminal.

Can anybody please me with this.

Comment: Have you checked if the phpmyadmin port is open to access in the RDS? (check in the current security groups)

Comment: Port 80, 8080 & 3306 have been allowed in the RDS. Should we allow any other port ?

Comment: Check if PHPMyAdmin is using any of these ports. Also you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402482/using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds

Comment: @F.Igor the reference link that you have provided is for Apache server and we are using Nginx. How can we check that PHPMyAdmin is running on which port ?

Comment: To test the port 8080 can use the command `netstat -anp tcp | grep ":8080"` and see if it's any service running in this port