# phpMyAdmin configuration on external database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [connect to external server by using php myAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722064/connect-to-external-server-by-using-php-myadmin)

My web host provides databases on separate servers, so "localhost" isn't an option for me. How do I setup phpMyAdmin configuration storage to use an external server?

I tried: 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'dbname.dbserver.host.com';`
and 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'dbname@dbserver.host.com';`

but those did not work. Any suggestions?

Here's my setup...
FreeBSD 7.3-RELEASE-p2
Apache/2.2.22
MySQL 5.0.91-log
mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev
phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.1
using config authentication

I put the setup for my configuration database into a config block for a regular, non-configuration database in config.inc.php and it works fine using something like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'dbuser';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'dbpass';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = array('dbname');
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbserver.host.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbserver.host.com'; // use host (I removed dbname.)
```

**EDIT 1**

test direct connection:

```
mysql --host=dbserver.host.com --user=*** --password=***
```

Your setup should be work. Otherwise ask for support. (need a SSL connection?, security certificate? etc)

Comment: I tried it like this: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'dbname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbname.dbserver.host.com';` and then again without the 'pmadb' line, but neither worked (quitting browser each time). I still get `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ... not OK`

Comment: perfectweb: this is not so hard to solve. please add info about your server environment (ubuntu, centos, etc). for example if you use `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php` (ubuntu) maybe you must set `$dbserver`, in it. etc...

Comment: I added my server setup to the question

Comment: Yes, I can direct connect to the server, but configuration storage is still not working with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbserver.host.com';`