# Accessing Multiple Remote Servers with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

Basically all the guides on this say the same thing. "Edit the config.inc.php file." This isn't working for me. I've even removed the file completely because editing it doesn't have any effect. And phpMyaAdmin loads fine without the file. So, I assume I've got something else going on that's preventing this config from being loaded.

Where do I go from here? Could it be a problem with my phpMyAdmin install? It is working besides this. For reference, this is on a fresh Debian web server with the LaMp stack installed.

Answer (score 0):

Where is you `config.inc.php` file placed? Ensure it is placed at the phpmyadmin root folder.

Are you sure it is readable by the user running the web server? If in doubt, try setting the file permission to readable for everyone with the command:

`chmod a+x config.inc.php`.

It that works, your problem was there and you just have to set proper permissions to this file (don't let it public readable).

If this isn't the problem, you could try to ensure your config file is valid by generating it with the phpMyAdmin setup page as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722064/connect-to-external-server-by-using-phpmyadmin/30423862#30423862).